# Include query result to List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a list of Hospitals

Hospital model:

```
public class Hospital
{
    [Key]
    public int HospitalID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HospitalSpeciality> HospitalSpecialities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserHospital> UserHospitals { get; set; }
}
```

and I have users associated to hospital. Model:

```
public class UserHospital
{
    [Key]
    public int UserHospitalID { get; set; }

    public int HospitalID { get; set; }
    public Hospital Hospitals { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Users { get; set; }
}
```

I need, on my list, return also the number of the user's that are associated to the Hospital.

This query is easy if I have only 1 hospital, but in my scenario, I have a list of hospitals

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = db.Hospitals.ToList();
        return View(result);
    }
```

I really don't know how to include the result of the query (number of users) on my list.

My view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.HospitalID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.HospitalID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.HospitalID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: `<td>@item.UserHospitals.Count()</td>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke "The object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: You may need to use `var result = db.Hospitals.Include(x => x.UserHospitals).ToList();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm using this `@item.UserHospitals.Where(i => i.Users.Active == true).Count()` BUT I have the same error, I cannot include "Users" on controller because it isn't associated to Hospitals

Comment: Can you try this at your controller; `db.Hospitals.Where(x => x.UserHospitals.Where(c => c.Users.Active == true)).ToList();`

Comment: @B.Yaylaci It does not work, [see here](https://i.gyazo.com/855a626f8cce3cff409f631221d5f255.png)

Comment: Sorry my bad, hope this helps; `db.Hospitals.SelectMany(x => x.UserHospitals).Where(c => c.Users.Active == true).ToList();`

Comment: @B.Yaylaci Sorry, it's returning [this](https://i.gyazo.com/02a987ff3a52fc227f33e0179c0759fc.png) error now

Comment: It is the issue that view's model is different than the model you gave return View(model), model is UserHospitals because of the query. We can use that query by starting at the end but I wonder about Why Stephen's answer didn't work? In the controller `var result = db.Hospitals.Include(x => x.UserHospitals).ToList();` will set UserHospitals and you should be able to get count at the controller easily.

Comment: Yes, on this query I only use `Hospital` and `UserHospital`, but I also need to use `User` in order to know if it's active or not, when I try to include `User` to query, I don't have that option or if I force, I get that error. @B.Yaylaci

Comment: Try this and after that I promise that I will leave this topic :) `db.UserHospitals.Where(c => c.Users.Active == true).SelectMany(x=> x.Hospitals).ToList();`

Comment: Ahah, I still getting error on `SelectMany'. But the problem is now solved. thanks for all help and time! @B.Yaylaci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to ensure the users are being returned in the query... Like so:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = db.Hospitals
                   .Include("UserHospitals")
                   .Include("UserHospitals.Users")
                   .ToList();
    return View(result);
}
```

Even if they are virtual, lazy loading won't occur because you are accessing the property in your razor view. The `Include` is forcing Eager Loading.

Alternatively, expose another Dbset...

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Now you can select the following:

```
db.Users.Where(x => !x.active).ToList();
```

Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: I just copy-pasted your query, then i put `@item.UserHospitals.Where(w => w.Users.Active == true).Count()` on my view and it's working. Thanks!!!

Comment: Glad I could help, I really would suggest, for performance reasons, changing the scope of your ViewModel to just a List of Users :) If you have need for all the information, maybe consider Partial pages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm new on ASP.NET and it's my first project with this, my goal is to have the project complete, then, next step is about performance :)